# Correct way to move your character node with Touch buttons?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, xcode6

I'm starting with the SpriteKit, and actually i want to move my Hero in a game by a buttons on screen.
 But i want the hero move as user stay pressing the button, if use take your finger off the button the Hero stop moving.

At first i think about use the touchesBegan(and End) with booleans, when user tap set the boolean true and star an action that moves Hero if bolean is true, and when user take off button set to false.
 i think this method is pretty bad, further take into consideration use sprite animations ( actually i have no idea how ir works)

i know this question isn`t very good but i search for something like this and i have found nothing too specific. Thx

Comment: that method is pretty standard, not pretty bad

Comment: really? is not using something like longPress? these virtual analogic sticks in some games are made with simular method but using the touch as moved? and booleans?

Comment: In this case you would set a "moving" flag when touchesbegan (in the correct area) and clear the flag when touches ended/cancelled. More complex systems (virtual or real joypads) essentially do the same thing.